Combining Transition with KeepAlive in Vue3.js
I took this example from Vue SFC Playground and added a Transition. The problem is that in order for the transition to work, I need to provide the div with the changing key () but that breaks the KeepAlive. The CompA and CompB component reloads as if there is no KeepAlive.
<script setup>
import { shallowRef, } from 'vue'
import CompA from './CompA.vue'
import CompB from './CompB.vue'

const current = shallowRef(CompA)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="demo">
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="current" :value="CompA" /> A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="current" :value="CompB" /> B</label>
    <br/>Curent:{{current.__name}}
    <Transition mode="out-in">
      <div :key="current.__name">
        <KeepAlive>
          <component :is="current" :key="current.__name"></component>
        </KeepAlive>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.v-enter-from,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

///CompA.vue:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const count = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
  <p>Current component: A</p>
  <span>count  : {{ count }}</span>
  <button @click="count++">+</button>
</template>

///CompB.vue:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const msg = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <p>Current component: B</p>
  <span>Message is: {{ msg }}</span>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>


<Transition> needs the actual components to have a single root element. Simply wrap your CompA and CompB templates with a div, then remove the div between Transition and KeepAlive
<Transition mode="out-in">
  <KeepAlive>
    <component :is="current" :key="current.__name"></component>
  </KeepAlive>
</Transition>

CompA.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Current component: A</p>
    <span>count  : {{ count }}</span>
    <button @click="count++">+</button>
  </div>
</template>

CompB.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Current component: B</p>
    <span>Message is: {{ msg }}</span>
    <input v-model="msg">
  </div>
</template>

working Vue Playground

The problem with that aproach is that I may not have controll over the components that I load into the  element.

Are the components third party? Most third party component libraries adhere to 1 root element per component.  Even though Vue 3 doesn't require it (whereas Vue 2 did), it's arguably still good practice to use 1 root element.  For any first party components, making sure all your components are wrapped in a single div will guarantee you have no issues, and it is a literal requirement of the <Transition> component that there be only 1 root (it's the only way for the CSS to make any sense). Unfortunately, there's no way of getting around it without rolling your own custom solution.
